# Explicit computation of inertia stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, algebraic-stacks

I am learning algebraic stacks myself with some reference recommended by my friends. I know from [here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Erehmann/ECM/cdrom/3ecm/pdfs/pant3/fantechi.pdf) Section 6.1 that an explicit description of the fibre product of stacks $\mathfrak{X}\times_\mathfrak{Y} \mathfrak{Z}$ for $f:\mathfrak{X}\to \mathfrak{X},g:\mathfrak{Z}\to \mathfrak{Y}$ is: the objects are $(x,y,\alpha)$ where $\alpha:f(x)\to g(z)$ is a morphism in a fiber of $\mathfrak{Y}$. I guess here a fiber of $\mathfrak{Y}$ means the groupoid $\mathfrak{Y}(T)$ for some scheme $T$ in the base site.

Then I try to use this to compute inertia stack and stabilizer group space. The inertia stack is the fiber product $\mathfrak{X}\times_{\mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}}\mathfrak{X}$. By the above description, the objects of $\mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}$ are $(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2$ are objects in $\mathfrak{X}$, and $Isom((x_1,x_2),(x_1',x_2'))=Isom(x_1,x_1')\times Isom(x_2,x_2')$. Also, the diagonal map is clearly both diagonal on objects and morphisms. So the objects in $\mathfrak{X}\times_{\mathfrak{X}\times\mathfrak{X}}\mathfrak{X}$ are $(x_1,x_2,(g_1,g_2))$, where $g_1,g_2\in Isom(x_1,x_2)$.

However, I saw from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4712.pdf) section 6.1 that Inertia stack $\mathcal{I}$ has objects $(x,g)$ where $x$ is an object in $\mathfrak{X}$, and $g\in Aut_{\mathfrak{X}}(X)$. And I don't think this can be identified with the result of the above calculation.

And the situation is also the same when I want to compute the stabilizer group space, so I wonder if the explicit description that's given at the beginning is right( for example, maybe $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ should be the same object), and if so, what is wrong with my computation.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can identify $(x_1, x_2, g_1, g_2)$ with $(x, g) = (x_1, g_2^{-1}g_1)$. In other words, identify the two objects using $g_1$, then $g_2$ can be viewed as an automorphism.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying these two categories (or groupoids) are not isomorphic, but only equivalent. And then two algebraic stacks are isomorphic as long as they have equivalent fibers( which are groupoids) and satisfy a certain descent condition, is that right?

Comment: @user837898 an equivalence of stacks is an equivalence of categories which preserves Cartesian arrows, if you want to take the Cartesian fibration approach. If you want to take the functorial approach then an equivalence of stacks is a natural isomorphism of functors. Notice this notion of equivalence has nothing to do with descent; after all, the category of stacks is fully faithfully embedded in the category of prestacks